# error during running Cronjobs in Rails whenever

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, debian, whenever

I've got some cronjobs for my rails application. I defined them in schedule.rb

When they are running then I got this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find minitest-5.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

I already have done sudo gem install minitest -v 5.7.0 - nothing has changed ...

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` for the project, as the cron user ?

Comment: And if you're using `rvm` you shouldn't use `sudo` to install gems

Comment: I run the app als user felix `bundle exec rails s` ... for whenever I need to do `sudo whenever -w`...